# How to decrease the recording starting latency in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, recording, low-latency

I want to show a picture on the screen and meanwhile start recording in js. I want the latency between them to be as small as possible since there must be latency after the code is executed and before the recording really starts.

Now I want to know is there any method to decrease such latency and the latency could be controlled at what level on a computer with a Win10 system and a normal soundcard. ~1ms, ~10ms or more?

Very much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show us some research, it's pretty hard to answer.

By the way MediaStreamTrack could help you to record screen and audio and there is in fact a parameters for latency.

The MediaTrackSettings dictionary's latency property is a double-precision floating-point number indicating the estimated latency (specified in seconds) of the MediaStreamTrack as currently configured.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings/latency